# Home directory when using sudo with -H flag

Tags: sudo

Trying to work out why:

```
me@mypc:~/$ sudo -H echo $HOME
/home/me
me@mypc:~/$ sudo echo $HOME
/home/me
```

Should the second one not be `/root` or am I misunderstanding -H flag?

EDIT:

Think that I may be looking at 2 different issues here, echo'ing $HOME always returns same dir even when `su root`

**TO CLARIFY: Just looking for a lay-man's term for explaining -H flag**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current shell is likely expanding $HOME variable before it is given to sudo for execution, thus it is always the same.
Try it for example like this:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo $HOME'
```

or

```
sudo env |grep HOME
```

Comment: `me@mypc:~$ sudo -H env |grep HOME`: HOME=/root
`me@mypc:~$ sudo env |grep HOME`: HOME=/home/me; nice one !